# need help on rails nesting routes

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I want to get a route like

```
GET /example/notifications/status, to: example/notification#status
POST /example/notifications/disable to: example/notification#disable
```

Here is what I did

```
resources :example, only => %i[index] do
  collection do
    resources :notifications, :only => [] do
      collection do
        get :status
        post :disable
      end
    end
  end  
end
```

it get the right path but it point to `notification#status` not `example/notification#status`

is there any way I can get both right path and controller expect code like

```
get "notifications/status", :to => "example/notifications#status"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `namespace` for this purpose like below,

in you `config/routes.rb` file

```
namespace :example do
   collection do
      get :status
      post :disable
   end
end
```

It will hit the `example/notification#status` action.

for more information see [here](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/v5.2/routing.html#controller-namespaces-and-routing)

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `resources` since you don't want (aparently) any param on your routes. Go for `namespace` instead:

```rb
namespace :example do
  namespace :notifications do
    get   'status'
    post  'disable'                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
  end
end
```

Gives you:

```sh
$ rails routes -g example
                       Prefix Verb URI Pattern                              Controller#Action
 example_notifications_status GET  /example/notifications/status(.:format)  example/notifications#status
example_notifications_disable POST /example/notifications/disable(.:format) example/notifications#disable
```

Comment: I can't change the top level root which is `resources :example, only => %i[index] do`. But seems like namespace under resource also can't work in the way I want.